# How do I DRY up this Nginx configuration?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I’m on **Nginx 0.8.54** trying to achieve the following as DRYly as possible:

- Proxy straight to `localhost:8060` if cookie `no_cache` is `true` or if request method isn’t `GET`.
- Otherwise serve static files from `$document_root/static/$uri`.
- If no such file exists, try `$document_root/cache/$uri` and `$document_root/cache/$uri.html`.
- If the request path is `/`, try no static files and only `$document_root/cache/index.html`.
- Finally fall back to `localhost:8060` if neither static nor cached files are found.

---

Current configuration file:

```
server {
    root /srv/web/example.com;
    server_name example.com;

    location @backend { proxy_pass http://localhost:8060; }

    location / {
        if ($cookie_no_cache = true) { proxy_pass http://localhost:8060; }
        if ($request_method != GET) { proxy_pass http://localhost:8060; }
        try_files /static/$uri /cache/$uri /cache/$uri.html @backend;
    }

    location = / {
        if ($cookie_no_cache = true) { proxy_pass http://localhost:8060; }
        if ($request_method != GET) { proxy_pass http://localhost:8060; }
        try_files /cache/index.html @backend;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
http {
  map $cookie_no_cache $cacheZone {
    default "";
    true    X;
  }

  server {
    root /srv/web/example.com;
    server_name example.com;

    error_page 405 = @backend;

    location / {
      try_files /cache$cacheZone/$uri.html /static$cacheZone/$uri
                /cache$cacheZone/$uri @backend;
    }

    location @backend {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8060;
    }
  }
}
```

Explanation.

1. Regarding "no_cache" cookie check. We are replacing it with Nginx `map`. Variable `$cacheZone` depends on the value of `$cookie_no_cache`. By default it's empty, but if there is a "no_cache=true" cookie, we set `$cacheZone` to any value to modify static file search path in `try_files` -- I hope you have no `/cacheX` and `/staticX` folders under your server root (if yes, choose another value for `$cacheZone`)
2. Nginx cannot apply HTTP methods `PUT` or `POST` to static files (this is meaningless), so that it issues HTTP error 405 "Not Allowed" in this case. We intercept it by `error_page` and pass the request to `@backend` location.

**Alternative approach**

Otherwise, use `proxy_cache`:

```
http {
  proxy_cache_path example:1m;

  server {
    root  /srv/web/example.com;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
      proxy_cache example;
      proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_no_cache;
      proxy_cache_valid 200 10s;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8060;
    }
  }
}
```